# Jquery/javascript detect click event inside tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

Simple as that, i want to detect when an image has been clicked inside a tinymce editor textarea.

is this really not achievable without creating a plugin for it? i cant use this method because im developing a plugin for drupal's wysiwyg module and i want to to be compatibale with all editors that wysiwyg supports.

onclick in the image attributes wont work,
.click listeners wont work.
the wysiwyg module api has no documentation whatsoever.

anybody knows any solution to this? i just want to detect when an image has been clicked, thats it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onClick) is a good place to start.

You can pass a setup function to bind TinyMCE events on initialization. Have a look at a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xgPzS/5/

HTML:

```
<textarea style="width:400px; height:400px;">
    some text
    <img src="http://www.hidekik.com/en/filelist/files/sample.jpg" />
</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$('textarea').tinymce({
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
            alert('Editor was clicked: ' + e.target.nodeName);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i get $("textarea").tinymce is not a function.
tinymce in all its glory is lovley but like i said, i would prefer not to use editor dependent functions to accomplish this. however it looks like i'll have to rewrite the plugin for tinymce instead as this does not appear to be possible

Comment: Apparently you are not using the TinyMCE jQuery plugin. Why did you tag jQuery then? Anyway, you can pass the above setup property wherever you call `tinymce.init()`. I think you should use editor dependent functions rather than some ugly hack that you can only hope it keeps working across different editors' future versions. Just write generic code of what you want to do, and plug it the proper way into each editor you want supported.

Comment: $('textarea') won't work here, because the editor consists of an editable iframe created by tinymce, the former textarea becomes hidden and won't react when clicked!!!

Comment: @Thariama: yes, that was just an example selector to create the editor from. It needs to be put wherever the editor is initialized. As he tagged jQuery, I assumed he's using the TinyMCE jQuery plugin, which takes exactly the same parameters and properties, and essentially exactly the same as `tinyMCE.init()`.

Comment: I tagged jQuery because Drupal uses it and i assumed the jQuery plugin would be loaded by the wysiwyg module. tinymce is and object and i can access it from the console however not in the code as it says its not a function. This could be because .init() has already been called. i'm trying to figure out how to use the Drupal.wysiwygInit() function to call the tinymce.init() early enough but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

In Tinymce 4.x jQuery version, I only managed to get the focus and blur events by using the following method in the setup

JavaScript:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.on('init', function() {
        $(ed.getDoc()).contents().find('body').focus(function(){
            alert('focus');
        });

        $(ed.getDoc()).contents().find('body').blur(function(){
            alert('blur');
        });  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by DarthJDG the [setup init param](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup) is the way to go here

```
tinyMCE.init({

    ...

    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
                alert('Img-Tag has been clicked!');
            }
        });
    },

    ....

});
```

Comment: That's not really different from my solution. ;)

Comment: it is. this part belongs inside the tinymce init function and $('textarea') won't work in your case

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach here has nothing to do with tinyMCE. As you wrote, you want to support multiple kinds of WYSIWYG editors.

My suggestion is that you simply use jQuery delegate events. You bind the event handler on your own dom element, somewhere "up stream" on the document. It will grab all the click events on the images that are nested below it, and then act accordingly.

See here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

I have used this method successfully several times to bind click events on elements that didn't yet exist (they are inserted to the dom dynamically by the user).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tinyEditor.hasFocus()` to check if the Editor has been clicked on.